# How to colorize individual columns in CSV file in terminal?

Tags: shell, csv, sh

Given `file.csv`:

```
0.99,Apple,Fruit
22.33,Banjo,Instrument
1.95,Chocolate,Snack
```

And `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile` (non-GNU):

```
CEND='\e[0;0m'
CRED='\e[0;31m'
CGREEN='\e[0;32m'
```

I can colorize the first column red like so:

```
for a in $(cut -f 1 -d, - < file.csv); do printf ${CRED}$a${CEND}'\n'; done
```

But how can I colorize the other columns so that I can then pipe the result to `column -s, -t` or another utility to display the entire CSV file?

Desired result:

```
0.99 Apple    Fruit
22.33Banjo    Instrument
1.95 ChocolateSnack
|____|________|_________|
 RED GREEN     BLACK
```

I'm trying to get the columns delimited using colors; not by tabs or spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use IFS.

```
CEND='\e[0;0m'
CRED='\e[0;31m'
CGREEN='\e[0;32m'


while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3
do
    printf "${CRED}$col1${CGREEN}$col2${CEND}$col3\n"
done < path_to_csv_file
```

### EDIT

```
CEND='\e[0;0m'
CRED='\e[0;31m'
CGREEN='\e[0;32m'

CSV_FILE='csv'

read max1 max2 <<< $(awk -F, ' { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)LENGTH[i]=((x=length($i))>LENGTH[i]?x:LENGTH[i])} END { print LENGTH[1] " " LENGTH[2] }' $CSV_FILE)

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3
do
    printf "${CRED}%-*s${CGREEN}%-*s${CEND}%s\n" ${max1} "${col1}" ${max2} "${col2}" "${col3}"
done < $CSV_FILE
```

Comment: Great! Now how would you go about aligning those columns by expanding the length of short literals so that they match longest one as per my example?

Comment: I edit the previous post with the changes.
To retrieve the maximum length of a column we use awk.
Finally, it only remains to fill spaces.

Comment: Better `printf "${CRED}%s${space1}${CGREEN}%s${space2}${CEND}%s\n" "${col1}" "${col2}" "${col3}"` preventing problems with fields containing `%s`.

Comment: Read both lengths with one `read length1 length2 <<< $(awk -F, ' { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)LENGTH[i]=((x=length($i))>LENGTH[i]?x:LENGTH[i])}
           END { print LENGTH[1] " " LENGTH[2] }' $CSV_FILE)`

Comment: When you calculate the max length of col1 and col2, you can use `printf "${CRED}%-*s${CGREEN}%-*s${CEND}%s\n" ${max1} "${col1}" ${max2} "${col2}" "${col3}"`

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider using `python` ? If Yes, then

```
$ cat file.csv
some,name,thing
0.99,Apple,Fruit
22.33,Banjo,Instrument
1.95,Chocolate,Snack
```

And the `colorize_csv.py` file,

```
# colorize_csv.py
# Usage: `python colorize_csv.py file.csv`

from csv import DictReader
import sys


green = "\033[32m"
red = "\033[31m"
yellow = "\033[33m"
reset = "\033[00m"
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    reader = DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        line = "{}{:<10s} {}{:<10s} {}{:<10s}{}".format(red, row['some'], green, row['name'], yellow, row['thing'], reset)
        print(line)
```

Comment: I don't always stray away from the Unix philosophy, but when I do, I prefer golang.